# SSMS will not let me create a PK FK relationship

Tags: sql, ssms, relationship

First, let me say that I am a newbie and that I have read many other posts with the same problem.  I have a table called "AllPeople", and in that table I have an integer column called "Ethnicity", which I want to be a foreign key that points at a record in my "RefEthnicities" table. I keep getting the following message:

> Unable to create relationship 'FK_AllPeople_RefEthnicities'.
>   The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_AllPeople_RefEthnicities". The conflict occurred in database "MVC-Cemeteries-Dev", table "dbo.RefEthnicities", column 'ID'.

I set up the relationship in the "AllPeople" table and told it that the primary key is the ID column in the "RefEthnicities" and the foreign key is the "Ethnicity" column in the "AllPeople" table.  What am I doing wrong?  My RefEthnicities table is new; no data in it.

While in design mode I set the ID field in the "RefEthnicities" table set as primary key by clicking the small box to the left of the name "ID", and down below in this same window in the column properties tab, I told it to set the index specification to "yes".

I am sure it is something simple that I am doing but I can't figure it out.
[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eZyOB.png)

[Constraint Folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQcbH.png)

[Setting Up PK FK Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NDSDS.png)

Comment: Hi Adam, sounds simple enough. Could you please add to your question a screenshot of what you're trying to do or add the script? Another option is simply to do F5 (refresh) on the table: maybe the constraint is created and you just don't see it? Check under table -> constraint and table -> keys

Comment: You need to populate the `RefEthnicities` table with all the distinct `Ethnicities` values from the `AllPeople` table, before setting up the FK relationship.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I first tried creating the table with the ethnicity values in it, and after saving it I went to make the FK PK relationship.  When I got the error described above, I deleted the table, and started again, but this time I make the link to begin with before filling the ethnicity reference table with values.  Still get the error.

Comment: The confusing part is that it worked just fine when I used this same process for two other reference tables, and I can save values in the tables and do look up's on them from my controller.  Since I used the same process to set up all three reference tables, why would 2 of them work and not this one?

Comment: Links to pictures added in original post.

Answer (score 0):

As my limited information in the question, there 2 possibilities

NULL or Blank **`''`** value for column Ethnicity in table AllPeople

```
SELECT A.Ethnicity,A.*
FROM dbo.AllPeople A
WHERE ISNULL(A.Ethnicity,'')=''
```

Some values column Ethnicity in table AllPeople don't have parent in column ID in table RefEthnicities

```
SELECT A.Ethnicity,R.ID, *
FROM dbo.AllPeople A
LEFT JOIN RefEthnicities R
 ON A.Ethnicity=R.ID
WHERE R.ID IS NULL
```

If you get any rows in two queries, then you need to fix data in column Ethnicity in table AllPeople.

[Read](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/create-foreign-key-relationships?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: Yes, the AllPeople table can have either a null value (because one wasn't selected) or it can have a value ranging from 1 to 6 (the id values in the ethnicity table for my 6 ethnicities)

Answer (score 0):

Ok this still makes no sense.  If I create two brand new tables with the following:

table1
  ID  primary key int not nullable
  value varchar
  table2FK

table2
  ID primary key int not nullable
  value varchar

and in table1 I make a relationship between table2FK and Table2.ID, it works perfect with no data saved in the tables.  If I use the exact same process in my AllPeople and RefEthnicicties tables, I get the error.  This makes no sense.  What am I missing? 
adam

Answer (score 0):

That fixed it.  many thanks.  I had a record in my AllPeople table for ethnicity that had a value of 0.  Since I didn't have a record in the RefEthnicity Table with an ID of 0, it was telling me that I couldn't do this.

adam